# What is the difference between msgpack_pack and msgpack_serialize and MessagePack::pack?

Tags: php, serialization, php-extension, msgpack

msgpack implemented in php by [msgpack extension](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-php).

There are two functions `msgpack_pack` and `msgpack_serialize` and method `MessagePack::pack`. I do not know what is the difference between them. How to findout API of this extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.

This is `msgpack_serialize`, it calls function `php_msgpack_serialize`;

```
static ZEND_FUNCTION(msgpack_serialize)
{
    zval *parameter;
    smart_str buf = {0};

    if (zend_parse_parameters(
            ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &parameter) == FAILURE)
    {
        return;
    }

    php_msgpack_serialize(&buf, parameter TSRMLS_CC);

    ZVAL_STRINGL(return_value, buf.c, buf.len, 1);

    smart_str_free(&buf);
}
```

and  `msgpack_pack` is the alias of `msgpack_serialize`.

```
// in msgpack.c
static zend_function_entry msgpack_functions[] = {
    ZEND_FE(msgpack_serialize, arginfo_msgpack_serialize)
    ZEND_FE(msgpack_unserialize, arginfo_msgpack_unserialize)
    ZEND_FALIAS(msgpack_pack, msgpack_serialize, arginfo_msgpack_serialize)
    ZEND_FALIAS(msgpack_unpack, msgpack_unserialize, arginfo_msgpack_unserialize)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

`MessagePack::pack` is the object form of `msgpack_serialize`. It also calls `php_msgpack_serialize`:

```
static ZEND_METHOD(msgpack, pack)
{
    zval *parameter;
    smart_str buf = {0};
    int php_only = MSGPACK_G(php_only);
    MSGPACK_BASE_OBJECT;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(
            ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &parameter) == FAILURE)
    {
        return;
    }

    MSGPACK_G(php_only) = base->php_only;

    php_msgpack_serialize(&buf, parameter TSRMLS_CC);

    MSGPACK_G(php_only) = php_only;

    ZVAL_STRINGL(return_value, buf.c, buf.len, 1);

    smart_str_free(&buf);
}
```

Comment: `MessagePack` class has additional method `setOption`. Does the option affect `pack`?

Comment: Yes, it will affect `pack` and `unpack`, you can set it to `MSGPACK_CLASS_OPT_PHPONLY`. Once set, the data encoded only can transfer in php.